# how to add a fetch_status in perl

Tags: sql-server, perl, sql-server-2005, dbi

I have this code for SQL Server 2005, and it works properly

```
    declare @GroupID varchar(11)

    DECLARE ConMaster CURSOR FOR
    SELECT groupid from collectorgroup where (CollectionDate BETWEEN '08/01/2013 00:00:00'  and   '08/01/2013 23:59:59') AND oRnO <> ''

    OPEN ConMaster

         FETCH NEXT FROM ConMaster
         into @GroupID
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN
                exec x_sp_TDCR_Summ @GroupID


         FETCH NEXT FROM ConMaster
         into @GroupID
         END
             CLOSE ConMaster
             DEALLOCATE ConMaster
```

and i want to transfer it to a perl script and here's my code:

```
 use warnings;
 use DBI;

 my $dbfile = "dbname";
 my $user     = "sa";
 my $password = "";
 my $host = "localhost";
 my $dsn      = "dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};server=$host;database=$dbfile";
 my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password,
                   { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1 }
   ) || die "Error connecting to the database: $DBI::errstr\n";



 print("Enter month (in number):");
 my $mo=<>;
 chomp($mo);
 print("enter date: ");
 my $da=<>;
 chomp($da);
 print("Enter year: ");
 my $yr=<>;
 chomp($yr);

 my $ddate=$yr.'-'.$mo.'-'.$da." "."00:00:00";
 my $ddate2=$yr.'-'.$mo.'-'.$da." "."23:59:59";

 $sql="declare @GroupID varchar(11)

 DECLARE ConMaster CURSOR FOR
   SELECT groupid from collectorgroup where CollectionDate BETWEEN '$ddate'  and  '$ddate2'

 OPEN ConMaster

 FETCH NEXT FROM ConMaster
 into @GroupID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    exec x_sp_TDCR_Summ @GroupID


    FETCH NEXT FROM ConMaster
    into @GroupID
END
 CLOSE ConMaster
 DEALLOCATE ConMaster";

 my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
 $sth->execute();



 while(my $ref=$sql->fetchrow_arrayref()){
print "$ref->{'description'} $ref->{'amount'}\n";
 }
 $dbh->disconnect;
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Possible unintended interpolation of @GroupID in string at proc1.pl line 41.
Possible unintended interpolation of @FETCH_STATUS in string at proc1.pl line 41
.
Name "main::FETCH_STATUS" used only once: possible typo at proc1.pl line 41.
Name "main::hr" used only once: possible typo at proc1.pl line 7.
Name "main::mday" used only once: possible typo at proc1.pl line 7.
Name "main::min" used only once: possible typo at proc1.pl line 7.
Name "main::sec" used only once: possible typo at proc1.pl line 7.
Enter month (in number):08
enter date: 01
Enter year: 2013
DBD::ODBC::st execute failed: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Lin
e 1: Incorrect syntax near '('. (SQL-42000)
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword
 'WHILE'. (SQL-42000)
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Must declare the variable '@'. (S
QL-42000)
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword
 'END'. (SQL-42000)
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepare
d. (SQL-42000) at proc1.pl line 62, <> line 3.
DBD::ODBC::st execute failed: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Lin
e 1: Incorrect syntax near '('. (SQL-42000)
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword
 'WHILE'. (SQL-42000)
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Must declare the variable '@'. (S
QL-42000)
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword
 'END'. (SQL-42000)
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepare
d. (SQL-42000) at proc1.pl line 62, <> line 3.
```

what would be my code for this to run properly? and I'm also planning to insert the result set of my procedure to a PostgreSQL database but I haven't done it yet. I'm still working out on this code

Answer (score 1):

Escape `@` in your strings with `\` as perl wants to interpolate `@GroupID` array

```
 $sql = "declare \@GroupID varchar(11)
```

You can also use single quotes or `q{}` and `sprintf()` instead of interpolation,

```
 $sql = q{declare @GroupID .. CollectionDate BETWEEN '%s'  and  '%s' ..};
 $sql = sprintf($sql, $ddate, $ddate2);
```

Also replace:

```
 my $ref=$sql->fetchrow_arrayref()
```

with

```
my $ref=$sth->fetchrow_arrayref()
```

Check [perldoc DBI](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.630/DBI.pm#Outline_Usage) for reference.

Comment: i have tried using q{} and sprintf() but I got this error: Can't locate object method "fetchrow_arrayref" via package "declare @ GroupID varchar(11) and 
 (perhaps you forgot to load "declare @ GroupID varchar(11)

Comment: I have changed the code but it only displays the first set of results, for this procedure I should have 9 results when run on MSSQL server but when run thru PERL only the first set were displayed. It's as if I haven't placed it in a while loop

Comment: @user3004960 can't comment on your sql, but you can also try `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $sth->fetchall_arrayref()` instead of `while` loop.

Comment: still the same, only the first result sets were displayed

Comment: Read about odbc_more_results in the DBD::ODBC pod - you need it. BTW, it is not PERL, it is Perl or perl depending on how you use it.